# Adding child controls in a parent control during runtime vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parent-child

I have an ItemPanel control. It has a total of 11 buttons in it. Five of them are visible when the program is in State1 and the others in State2. My problem is, even after adding all controls in the Panel with visibility true at the beginning, only the first 5 controls are seen at any given time. I am using ItemPanel control of DotNetBar. This is my code:

```
Private Sub w_ShortcutPanel()   <<create panel and add buttons>>

    If IsNothing(ShortcutItemPanel) Then

        ShortcutItemPanel = New ItemPanel

        Dim bi As New ButtonItem()
        bi.Image = My.Resources.GeneralSettingNew
        bi.Name = "biGSForm"
        bi.Tooltip = "General Settings Form"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(0, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.ColorTable = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.V_Reinforcement
        bi.Name = "biReinfForm"
        bi.Tooltip = "Reinforcement Settings Form"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(1, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.ColorTable = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.sectionreport
        bi.Name = "biCreateSection"
        bi.Tooltip = "Create Sections"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(2, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.createregionnewBig
        bi.Name = "biRegionDetailing"
        bi.Tooltip = "Create Region"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(3, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.Autodesignnew
        bi.Name = "biAutoDesign"
        bi.Tooltip = "Auto-Design"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(4, bi)

        'Designed View Items
        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.layout_report
        bi.Name = "biLayout"
        bi.Tooltip = "Create GA Drawing"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(5, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.reinfreport
        bi.Name = "biReinforcement"
        bi.Tooltip = "Create Reinforcement Drawing"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(6, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.unlockDesign
        bi.Name = "biUnlockDesign"
        bi.Tooltip = "Unlock Design"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
        AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(7, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.Failurediagnostic
        bi.Name = "biFailureDiag"
        bi.Tooltip = "Failure Diagnostic"
        ' bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
    AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(8, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.calreport
        bi.Name = "biCalculationReport"
        bi.Tooltip = "Calculation Report"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
    AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(9, bi)

        bi = New ButtonItem
        bi.Style = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
        bi.Image = My.Resources.detailreport
        bi.Name = "biDetailReport"
        bi.Tooltip = "Detailed Report"
        'bi.Size = New Size(80, 80)
        bi.ItemAlignment = eItemAlignment.Near
    AddHandler bi.Click, AddressOf w_SomeFunction
        'ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Add(bi)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Insert(10, bi)

        Dim x, y As Double
        x = vpMainControl.Width - ShortcutItemPanel.Width - 50
        y = vpMainControl.Location.Y + 10
        Dim location As New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Location = location
        ShortcutItemPanel.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 10, 0)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Right
        ShortcutItemPanel.BackColor = vpMainControl.BackColor
        ShortcutItemPanel.AutoSize = True
        ShortcutItemPanel.AutoScaleMode = Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit
        ShortcutItemPanel.ItemSpacing = 0
        ShortcutItemPanel.HorizontalItemAlignment = eHorizontalItemsAlignment.Center
        vpMainControl.Controls.Add(ShortcutItemPanel)
        ShortcutItemPanel.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

<< This function is in a separate class to which I pass "vpMainControl" as a parameter. So I am accessing ShortcutItemPanel as vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel>>

```
Private Sub w_RefreshShortcutPanelItemsByViewMode()  <<set visibility when state changes>>

    For i As Integer = 0 To vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Count - 1

        Select Case vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i).Name
            Case "biGSForm", "biReinfForm", "biCreateSection", "biRegionDetailing", "biAutoDesign"
                If State1 Then vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i).Visible = False
                If Staate2 Then vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i).Visible = True
            Case "biFailureDiag", "biLayout", "biReinforcement", "biCalculationReport", "biDetailReport", "biUnlockDesign"
                If State1 Then vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i).Visible = True
                If State2 Then vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i).Visible = False
        End Select

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a variable named "ShortcutItemPanel" but you are not using it in the "refresh" method.  Simplest explanation is that vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel is not the same control.

Comment: the Refresh function is in a different class to which I pass the main form "vpMainControl", hence I access it like that. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question.

Comment: Then the simplest explanation is that "vpMainControl" is the wrong reference.  Try adding vpMainControl.Show() to the refresh method.

Comment: But it is already showing, as it is the form. On it, I have two buttons, which change the state. When I click either of these buttons, the respective buttons are turned on or off.

Comment: Well, if that were true then there would be no point in asking this question.  You'll need to stop assuming that it works when you can see that it doesn't.

Comment: w_ShortcutPanel() is called on vpMainControl.Load() (Form Event). When I click on buttons for State1 and State2, control moves to a class that does some calculations and in the end the w_Refresh function is called. Since ShortcutItemPanel is a control on vpMainControl and is always visible, I have to access it like vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel. It does not resize to show any number of visible items depending on the state. It always shows 5 items only. That's my problem. In state 2, it should show 6 items. The last one gets cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got this workaround temporarily, but I would still like answers as to why the container control does not resize with the child controls in it.

```
Private Sub w_AdjustShortcutPanelUI(ByVal v_Count As Integer)
    vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Width = (From itm As Object In vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items
                                              Select itm.Size.Width).Max * v_Count
    Dim x, y As Double
    x = vpMainControl.Width - vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Width - 50
    y = vpMainControl.Location.Y + 10
    Dim location As New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
    vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Location = location
End Sub
```

I am calling this function form the refresh function that I posted earlier:

```
Private Sub w_RefreshShortcutPanelItemsByViewMode()

    Dim iCount As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items.Count - 1
        With vpMainControl.ShortcutItemPanel.Items(i)
            Select Case .Name
                Case "biGSForm", "biReinfForm", "biCreateSection", "biRegionDetailing", "biAutoDesign"
                    If zbAutoDesign Then .Visible = False
                    If Not zbAutoDesign Then .Visible = True
                Case "biFailureDiag", "biLayout", "biReinforcement", "biUnlockDesign", "biCalculationReport", "biDetailReport"
                    If zbAutoDesign Then .Visible = True
                    If Not zbAutoDesign Then .Visible = False
            End Select
            If .Visible = True Then iCount = iCount + 1
        End With
    Next

    'this fix is a work around for the problem of ShortcutPanel size.
    'ths size of the panel does not adjust according to the items in it.
    w_AdjustShortcutPanelUI(iCount)


End Sub
```

Any ideas might be helpful, as I don't think this is the optimum solution.